# Rails Has_And_Belongs_To_Many Relationships to deal with multiple ownership?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What happens right now is that when a user chooses to have a book belong to an author they make the selection and perfect. But I'd like for the book to also be able to be connected to a different author at the same time.

For example: The Talisman is written by both Stephen King and Peter Straub. Right now it can only connect to one author. Or for example if the same name of a book was being used by two different authors.

App > Models

```
User 
has_many :books

Book 
belongs_to :user, optional: true 
belongs_to :author, optional: true

Author 
has_many :books, dependent: :destroy
```

Is this a case in which I need to do has_and_belongs_to_many and create a join table?

Comment: I'm not sure how to expand this enough to turn it into a proper answer, so: Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Talisman is written by both Stephen King and Peter Straub. Right now it can only connect to one author.

Sounds like you need many to many relation here, because a book can belong to multiple authors and an author can write multiple books, so yes, specifying `has_and_belongs_to_many` relation and create a join table is the right approach here.

> Or for example if the same name of a book was being used by two different authors.

I think different books should have different records and ids in the database, but sure depends on your specific use cases.